# Like operator to compare two columns from two different table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

How can I pull the records from the first table (***Table_A***) which has an **Attr** column having embedded **CODE** values those contain *at least one uncommon* **CODE** value whenever compared to the second table (***Table_B***: *CODE* & *DESCR* cols.) so that I get table_C as the result? This is what I have so far:

```sql
Select * From Table_A
Where Attr like '%CODE%' AND
    not exist (select * from Table_B
               where Table_A.Attr LIKE '%'||Table_B.CODE||'%')
```

table A

| ID | Attr |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | CODE = A111 |
| 2 | CODE = 'A111, B222, C333, D444' |
| 3 | CODE = 'D444', 'E555', 'F666' |
| 4 | CODE = 'G777', 'B222' |
| 5 | ITEM = 'AFRD' AND CODE = 'C333' |
| 6 | ITEM = BYNM |

table_B

| CODE | DESCR |
| --- | --- |
| A111 | djiefljfe |
| D444 | qrrascjg |
| E555 | wpofler |
| F666 | nfosmwfa |
| G777 | losk |

table_C

| ID | Attr |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | CODE = 'A111, B222, C333, D444' |
| 4 | CODE = 'G777', 'B222' |
| 5 | ITEM = 'AFRD' AND CODE = 'C333' |

Comment: Is your result table correct? Only record ID=5 does not contain codes from Table_B.

Comment: ID= 2 contains B222 and C333
ID = 4 contains B222
which are not in table_b

Comment: This is not feasible with the SQL LIKE command. The `Attr` column must be split into single codes and the test must be applied to each one of those. @AlexPoole shows a possible SQL approach. The information in `Attr` is better suited for processing in the front-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as codes always follow items, you could extract the list of codes with:

```
regexp_substr(attr, '.*(CODE = ?)(.*?)', 1, 1, null, 2
```

and remove the spaces and quotes with

```
translate(regexp_substr(attr, '.*(CODE = ?)(.*?)', 1, 1, null, 2), q'^x' ^', 'x')
```

to get a simple comma-separated list of values to look for, like `G777,B222`; and then split *that* into individual elements, for example using recursive subquery factoring; and find any that don't exist in the other table.

Which is messy, but:

```
with cte (id, attr, codes) as (
  select id, attr,
    translate(
      regexp_substr(attr, '.*(CODE = ?)(.*?)', 1, 1, null, 2),
      q'^x' ^', 'x'
    )
  from table_a
),
rcte (id, attr, codes, pos, code) as (
  select id, attr, codes, 1, regexp_substr(codes, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, 1, null, 1)
  from cte
  where codes is not null
  union all
  select id, attr, codes, pos + 1, regexp_substr(codes, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, pos + 1, null, 1)
  from rcte
  where regexp_substr(codes, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, pos + 1, null, 1) is not null
)
select distinct r.id, r.attr
from rcte r
where not exists (
  select null
  from table_b b
  where b.code = r.code
)
```

gives

| ID | ATTR |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | CODE = 'A111, B222, C333, D444' |
| 4 | CODE = 'G777', 'B222' |
| 5 | ITEM = 'AFRD' AND CODE = 'C333' |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4d10097bc83b87fdb1a403eb42ff6ca6)

The `cte` gets the simple CSV values; `rcte` splits those up to individual components (and assumes there will be no empty elements), and then those individual values are checked with `not exists`. Which gives duplicate id/attr pairs, so `distinct` removes the duplicates; but you can also see which code(s) didn't exist if you want, by not applying distinct, and potentially using `listagg` to still get a single result per ID.

It's painful, but that's what happens with data stored like this...

Comment: Yes, this data is not normalized. The codes should be stored in a separate table.

Answer (score 0):

You must give `Table_A` an alias, so that you can reference it in the nested select:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
    Table_A A
WHERE
    Attr LIKE '%CODE%' AND
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM Table_B
        WHERE A.Attr LIKE '%'||Table_B.CODE||'%'
    )
```

Also, the keyword is `EXISTS` not `EXIST`.

SQL is not able to parse complex arbitrary expressions like `ITEM = 'AFRD' AND CODE = 'C333'` and to differentiate between `C333` being a code and `AFRD` being an item. However, if item ids are always different from codes this is not a problem.

See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/995f23/1/0

Comment: This query is only pulling Record ID = 5, I need it to pull 2 and 4 also. I am looking for all records that contains a code that is not in table B.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an outer join among *Table_A* and *Table_B* in order to obtain unmatched codes after converting comma separated codes to the newly generated rows per each individual code through use of regular expression functions along with a hierarchical query such as

```
WITH a0 AS
(
 SELECT id, CASE WHEN INSTR(attr, 'CODE')>0 THEN
                      REGEXP_REPLACE(attr,'(.*CODE =)+') 
                  END AS codes
   FROM Table_A
), a AS
(   
 SELECT id, TRIM(BOTH CHR(39) FROM TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(codes,'[^,]+',1,level)) ) AS codes
   FROM a0
  WHERE codes IS NOT NULL 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(codes, ',') + 1
    AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
    AND PRIOR id = id   
)
SELECT a.*
  FROM Table_A a
  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id 
          FROM a 
          LEFT JOIN Table_B 
            ON code = codes 
         WHERE code IS NULL) b
     ON a.id = b.id
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=86c6af3ff968ddecb2c4669f3b220ae8)</kbd>